# incorporating twitter authentication in responsive design

Tags: api, twitter, sharing

I am working on a website which incorporates twitter sharing. To do this we ask for permission to write to the users twitter account. This works all well but we have one problem.

The website is responsive and has a high percentage of mobile device users. The current implementation uses popup windows for both the authorization and posting.

Is there any way to implement this without the usage of popup windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect on the current page instead of using a popup (when on mobile).

Comment: great idea. wonder why I didn't think about that. Is there a way to pass an additional parameter from the website to twitter which would then be added to the callbackurl?

Comment: Yes, you can add parameters to your callback URL. See the login flow documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter